# How can I express a time in a specific time zone?

Tags: ruby

I have a Time object and I want to change its time zone without changing the logical time it represents. For example, 2015-08-21 15:00:00 +00:00 would become 2015-08-21 10:00:00 -05:00, if I chose to convert the Time to the UTC-5 time zone. How can I do this?

I am using Ruby 2.0; I am not using Rails.

**Edit:** The `getlocal` method that @Tasos Stathopoulos mentions mostly works, but if you call `zone` on the result you get `nil`. This is understandable—there’s not a one-to-one mapping of time offsets to time zone abbreviations, so the system has no way of knowing which `zone` it should give you—but I would like the result to have a certain zone that I specify.

Comment: Rails has implemented exactly what you want:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb

`TimeWithZone` class keeps a property about the `TimeZone` of the instance. Rails has also implemented `TimeZone` which is a mapping to `TZInfo` a ruby timezone library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Time#getlocal` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#getlocal-method).

```
irb(main):001:0> time = Time.now
=> 2015-08-21 21:45:40 +0300
irb(main):002:0> time.getlocal('-05:00')
=> 2015-08-21 13:45:40 -0500
irb(main):003:0> time = time.getlocal('-05:00')
=> 2015-08-21 13:45:40 -0500
irb(main):004:0> time
=> 2015-08-21 13:45:40 -0500
```

Comment: I realized that this doesn’t do exactly what I need it to… see the edit I made to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 require 'time'
 (Time.now.utc + Time.zone_offset("EDT")).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S EDT")

 => "04/20/2023 14:49:05 EDT"
```